# How to get recommendations for indexes in ASE?

Tags: sap-ase

I'm trying to optimize few queries that our application dynamically generates.
So far I'm using:

```
set option show_missing_stats on
```

However the setting only mentions missing statistics. Both MSSQL and Oracle give recommendations in terms of which indexes should be created to optimize query. Is there anything like that in Sybase ASE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sybase ASE unfortunately hasn't got a tool for indexes recommendation. As you said there is only `show_missing_stats` on Sybase ASE 15+.